# How to select an option using regular expression extractor in JMETER

Tags: regex, automated-tests, jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance

I have two select options.Based on first option selected we can chose the second option.
Based on the Industry we choose we have to select the category.
My code is

```
<select name="data[Product][industry_id]" class="form-control" id="ProductIndustryId">
<option value="">-Select Industry-</option>
<option value="1">Textiles</option>
<option value="2">Automobiles</option>
<option value="10">Home Improvement</option>
</select>

<select name="data[Product][category_id]" class="form-control" id="ProductCategoryId">
</select>
```

On Selection of my industry will automatically populate the category.But was not able to select the industry using regex

Xpath extractor

```
 Reference name: indus
 Xpath Query:         
                //select[@id='ProductIndustryId']/option[text()='Automobiles']/@value 
 Default Value: NONE
```

Any help...

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather go for [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) as it [isn't recommended to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).

For instance if you want to get value for `Automobiles` which is `2` you need following expression:

```
//select[@id='ProductIndustryId']/option[text()='Automobiles']/@value
```

I guess that the category is being auto-populated using JavaScript. JMeter isn't capable of executing JavaScript so you'll need to do the mapping manually.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Is Referencing xpath extractor is same as regex? If so still not able to select the option

Comment: Yes, you can refer to variables the same way, either by `${variablename}` or via function as `${__V(variablename)}` which is useful for combining several variables and evaluating result.

Comment: Still the option is not selected

Comment: JMeter won't trigger JavaScript execution, you'll have to populate your request manually